# OpenSSL IP Address and Case-Insensitive Host Name Validation

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, activemq-classic

I am attempting to get SSL communication working between ActiveMQ and a C++ client.  I have successfully generated a server certificate using the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias ActiveMQ -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA
    -validity 4383 -keystore ActiveMQ.ks -storepass <PASSWORD> -keypass <PASSWORD>
    -dname "CN=ActiveMQ,O=My Company,OU=My OU,L=My City,ST=My State,C=US"
    -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1
```

Then exported it to PEM format with:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias ActiveMQ -keystore ActiveMQ.ks -storepass <PASSWORD>
    -rfc -file ActiveMQ.pem
```

And finally, include the following line immediately after the call to `activemq::library::ActiveMQCPP::initializeLibrary()`:

```
decaf::lang::System::setProperty("decaf.net.ssl.trustStore", "ActiveMQ.pem");
```

When I try to connect to the host `ssl://localhost:61617`, everything works as expected.  However, when I try to connect to either `ssl://LOCALHOST:61617` or `ssl://127.0.0.1:61617`, I get the error:

> Server Certificate Name doesn't match the URI Host Name value.

Does anyone know how to modify the behavior of the OpenSSL certificate validator?  It should be case-agnostic when checking against DNS entries, and I want it to check against the IP addresses as well.  I expect both of the failing connection strings (see above) to work.

In case it matters, my environment is setup as follows:

```
OS          : Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64
Compiler    : Visual Studio 2008 Professional
ActiveMQ    : 5.13.1
ActiveMQ-CPP: 3.8.4
OpenSSL     : 1.0.2j
APR         : 1.5.2/1.5.4/1.2.1
JRE         : 8u112
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"Does anyone know how to modify the behavior of the OpenSSL certificate validator?"* - OpenSSL, prior to version 1.1.0, did ***not*** perform hostname validation. Its likely coming from RabbitMQ or your client software. Also see [Hostname validation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation) on the OpenSSL wiki and [Setting up c++ client app using CMS using SSL client certificate auth](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/setting-up-c-client-app-using-CMS-using-SSL-client-certificate-auth-td4664686.html) on the RabbitMQ mailing list.

Comment: @jww From your first link, it appears OpenSSL 1.0.2j does provide hostname validation, but it isn't enabled by default.  I looked into the ActiveMQ code, and it is calling `SSL_set_verify(..., SSL_VERIFY_PEER, someInternalHandler)` to enable this validation.  Their internal handler is essentially a no-op, which means that the validator shipped with OpenSSL is misbehaving.  I will look into the code in OpenSSL that actually performs the validation, to see how difficult it would be to enhance it as I requested.